# Typed relation query using Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma, remix.run

I have a TypeScript Remix.run project where I am looking to switch to using Prisma ORM for my querying needs. I have a query that needs to join multiple tables. This `schema.prisma` was generated by `npx prisma db generate`. I am including only the applicable models for this question:

```
model discord_channels {
  id                String              @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  channel_id        String              @unique
  guild_id          String
  name              String
  type              Int
  log               Int                 @default(1)
  created_at        DateTime            @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at        DateTime            @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  parent_channel_id String?
  discord_guilds    discord_guilds      @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [guild_id], onUpdate: Restrict)
  discord_messages  discord_messages[]
  proposal_channels proposal_channels[]

  @@id([id, channel_id])
}

model discord_guilds {
  id               String             @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  guild_id         String             @unique
  name             String
  active           Int                @default(1)
  log              Int                @default(1)
  created_at       DateTime           @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at       DateTime           @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  qa               Int                @default(0)
  discord_channels discord_channels[]
  discord_messages discord_messages[]
}

model discord_messages {
  id                        String           @id
  guild_id                  String
  channel_id                String
  thread_id                 String?
  author_id                 String
  author_tag                String
  content                   String?
  attachments               Json?
  embeds                    Json?
  parent_message_id         String?
  created_at                DateTime         @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at                DateTime         @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  discord_created_timestamp DateTime         @db.Timestamptz(6)
  thread_name               String?
  discord_channels          discord_channels @relation(fields: [channel_id], references: [channel_id], onUpdate: Restrict)
  discord_guilds            discord_guilds   @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [guild_id], onUpdate: Restrict)
  qa2                       qa2?
}

model qa2 {
  id               String           @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  message_id       String           @unique
  question         String
  is_relevant      Int
  model            String?
  logs             Json
  is_manual        Int              @default(0)
  downvotes        Int              @default(0)
  upvotes          Int              @default(0)
  hidden           Int              @default(0)
  created_at       DateTime         @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at       DateTime         @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  answer           String?
  no_answer        Int              @default(0)
  discord_messages discord_messages @relation(fields: [message_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict)
}
```

I need a query that selects every record in `qa2` where `no_answer = 0` and `is_relevant = 1`. `qa2` needs to get the `channel_id` and `guild_id` from `discord_messages` using the FK `qa2.message_id = discord_messages.id`. The reason for that is that I need `discord_channels.name` and `discord_guilds.name` for the associated IDs.

This was my attempt at typing the query:

```js
type Qa2WithRelations = Awaited<
    ReturnType<typeof db.qa2.findMany>
>;
```

This is the query that TypeScript is complaining about:

```js
const qa2Data: Qa2WithRelations = await db.qa2.findMany({
        where: {
            no_answer: 0,
            is_relevant: 1,
        },
        select: {
            question: true,
            answer: true,
            discord_messages: {
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    discord_channels: {
                        select: {
                            name: true,
                        }
                    },
                    discord_guilds: {
                        select: {
                            name: true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

The error: `Type '{ question: true; answer: true; discord_messages: { select: { id: true; discord_channels: { select: { name: true; }; }; discord_guilds: { select: { name: true; }; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'qa2Select'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'discord_messages' does not exist in type 'qa2Select'.`

I am not able to infer where the error is. It seems that `discord_messages` exists on the `qa2` model. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually type `qa2Data` - Prisma will add the type for you. Prisma automatically calculates the output TypeScript type based on what you pass into `select`, and the type that it emits will include everything (including nested properties, or models/tables that you have joined.)

This is what your call would look like:

```js
const qa2Data = await db.qa2.findMany({
        where: {
            no_answer: 0,
            is_relevant: 1,
        },
        select: {
            question: true,
            answer: true,
            discord_messages: {
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    discord_channels: {
                        select: {
                            name: true,
                        }
                    },
                    discord_guilds: {
                        select: {
                            name: true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

The type that it emits will look *something* (not exactly, just guessing) like this. Prisma generates this type for you - You don't have to!

```
{
  question: string;
  answer: string | null;
  discord_messages: {
    id: string;
    discord_channels: Array<{
      name: string;
    }>;
    discord_guilds: Array<{
      name: string;
    }>
  };
}
```

If you need to know in advance what kind of data you'll be working with (or need to reuse this emitted type somewhere else), I recommend using `Prisma.validator` to generate the appropriate argument ahead of time. That way, you know what arguments to pass to the Prisma client AND you always know what the shape of the output data is going to be.

Documentation:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/prisma-validator

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types